# Game Theory: Maxmin Value for matching pennies game??

Tags: game-theory

The problem presented is an augmented ver of matching pennies so P1 gets doubled payoffs for picking heads (we are given this matrix so assume this is correct).

|  | Heads | Tails |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Heads | (2,-2) | (2,-2) |
| Tails | (-1,1) | (1,-1) |

One of the questions regarding this game is about finding the Maxmin value for P1. I was a bit lost on the explanation in class & I've been trying to figure out how to calculate it from online explanations. So I've been trying to follow this explanation of Maxmin values for reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sx9cWFLDFmw

Following the method explained in the video i calculated the utilies of P1:

- U1(player 2 plays H) = 3p-1
- U1(player 2 plays T) = 1-3p

& then make 3p-1=1-3p

but I think this is where I get confused.
So then I get 6p-1=1... essentially so 6p=2 and getting p=1/3.

The final step is apparenly plugging this p value back into either of the utilities:

- U1(player 2 plays H) = 3p-1 = 3(1/3)-1
- U1(player 2 plays T) = 1-3p = 1-3(1/3)

But doing so gives me 0

In the example from our class, the result for regular matching pennies was 1/2 which I still am not sure how that was worked out...

|  | Heads | Tails |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Heads | (1,-1) | (1,-1) |
| Tails | (-1,1) | (1,-1 |

Can anyone help clarify my gaps in knowledge? I am sorry if these are silly questions but I am doing my first module in Game Theory so a lot of this takes a bit of time to sink in. Thanks!

Comment: $6p-1=1$ does not imply $p=0$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: ah yes sorry i've fixed it now